# Score counter with the "counting up" shown/animated

Tags: java, increment, game-development

I'm trying to create a visual representation of the score counter counting up to the player's score, for that "retro" feel. I have the counter programmed in fine in order to show the player's score. What I'm having trouble with is the "counting up" representation. I searched around on S/O expecting to find something like this actually, however, maybe because of the wording of my search, I did not have any luck.

```
public class ScoreCounter {
  private Font font = null;
  private int width = 0;
  private long score = 0, targetScore = 0;

  public void setFont(Font newFont) {
    font = newFont;
  }

  public void increment(int increment) {
    for (int i = increment; 0 < i; i--) {
      score++;
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 30));
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    width = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(Long.toString(score));
    g.drawString(Long.toString(score), 764 - width, 30);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you using as the user interface to your game?  Do you want to print the text to the text console, or is your game in a window or similar?

Comment: @MarkPeters Its a drawn string on a jPanel.

Comment: where are ``score`` and ``targetScore`` defined? Perhaps the question would be clearer if you provided a ``class`` definition.

Comment: @nathanesau sure hang on, however I'm not sure that will help much.

Comment: Do you have a game loop where you paint a frame N times every second?

Comment: @MarkPeters Essentially I have a  game class that paints the score counter every time there is a collision with an object

Comment: @Wizerman: Ok, the reason I'm asking is because you will take different approaches if your game is loop-driven (i.e. always update the game state and canvas at a rate of ~50 frames per second) versus event-driven (i.e. only update when there's a change).  It's trivial to add animations like this when you already have a rendering loop; with an event-driven architecture you need to cause events that will cause the animation frames to be drawn.

Comment: @MarkPeters Completely understand what you're saying, but, I am very new to Java and especially Java with graphics so to go back and change the style of the game from where I am now would take longer than I want. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game should have some concept of 'a cycle' IE: a frame. You should have a function that is included in the 'list of functions to call per cycle' that calculates the new value for you.

```
public void calculateScore()
  {
    newScore = previousScore + SCORE_PER_CYCLE_ADDED;
    // then you add in the scores from 'whatever' they did in that cycle
    // such as killing enemies
    for(Enemy defeatedEnemy: EnemiesDefeatedThisCycle){
          newScore += defeatedEnemy.getScoreValue();
    }
    // collected points items
    for(Item itemCollected: CollectedItemsThisCycle){
          newScore += itemCollected.getScoreValue();
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere you have something that updates on the GUI the player's new score per frame.

Comment: You can add in logic that it should only add in `SCORE_PER_SECOND_ADDED` when the current time has elapsed into the new second. (by keeping the 'previous' system time's second stored and only adding score when the timestamp is greater than the next second's (or 10 seconds or however you want your game to increment counting score, etc.)

Comment: I see. Now I'm assuming the key here is **per frame**, because I have a `for-loop` but it instantly updates the score and does not count up to it.

Comment: oh just saw your comment

Comment: Your 'for-loop' is the 'cycle' I was discussing. (I was being broad with my terms since I wasn't sure if you wrote your own code or were using an engine, etc.) But yes, just call `calculateScore()` in your loop, and then let it handle the 'logic' of how to add to the score.

Comment: The notion of 'cycle' and 'frames per second' are related, since you need to complete a 'cycle' before you can update your 'frame'. However, do not tightly couple your game's logic to that of your game's frame rate. (Such as limiting your framerate to 30/s. and then building into your `calculateScore()` that it counts 30 cycles than increments the score.) That is just bad/lazy design and will hurt you later if you ever want to improve/re-release/upgrade/etc your game. Since newer hardware is generally faster, and more Frames/second is objectively better (except when devs use above lazy design)